# How profit margin can be higher than operating margin?

Tags: stocks, financial-literacy, margin, profitability

I was looking at fundamentals for SalesForce ([CRM](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CRM/key-statistics?p=CRM)) and noticed that their profit margin higher than operating margin:

> Profitability
>   Profit Margin 1.48%
>   Operating Margin (ttm) 0.21%

In my understanding margins should go from higher to lower in this order:

1. Gross profit margin
2. Operating margin
3. Profit margin

Could anybody explain how is it possible for operating margin be higher than profit margin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the financials on the same site, https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/CRM/financials?p=CRM:

Operating income was $64MM. Then other income was $50MM and Tax expense was $-154MM (that is income expense is adding to income), less interest expense of $89MM. For a net imcome of $180MM.

Net income of $180MM is greater than operating income of $64MM, so profit margin will be greater than operating margin.

The stinky pile of poo is such a large negative income tax expense. That will not be sustainable and deserves scrutiny.

Comment: How tax expense could be negative?
Could it be because they overpaid taxes and got refund from IRS?

Comment: @VladPapko, beyond me skill to answer, but worthy of more research.

Comment: See bottom of page 54 and page 55 of http://s1.q4cdn.com/454432842/files/doc_financials/2017/Salesforce-FY-2017-Annual-Report.PDF

Comment: Thanks for searching this. Now it makes much more sense.
Also found article with general reasons of negative tax expense. In case you are interested: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/would-company-negative-income-taxes-but-net-income-income-statement-35332.html